# Non 0-1 integer programming

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, integer-programming

Many interesting combinatorial problems - graph coloring, maximal matching, set cover, and knapsack among others - can be reformulated as integer linear programs. One thing that all of these reformulations have in common is that they are so called 0-1 integer programs. That is, the variables in the program recieve values in $\{0,1\}$.

I'm preparing for a class I'm teaching on linear programming, and so I'd like to give a variety of interesting examples of integer programming.

My question is:
Is there an interesing combinatorial problem that can be restated as an integer linear program where the values of the variables are not necessarily 0-1?

Comment: Are the examples on the wikipedia page not something you can use?

Comment: Do you mean the Wikipedia page on integer programming? The examples given there are set packing, traveling salesman, SAT and vertex cover - all of which are restated as 0-1 integer linear programs.

Comment: Ah wait, I thought I saw a different one in the list. Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many formulations of, e.g., graph coloring problems (e.g. see [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmarecek/timetabling/asap2007-slides.pdf)), some of which are integer linear programming formulations where general integer variables are used.  You may want to show several approaches and compare/contrast them to give students deeper insight into the importance of formulation.